# Can we apply more than one transformation on image in xaml for windows 8 such as Translation,Rotation?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to apply multiple transformation on image such as rotate ,translate,etc 
Is it possible I got an error like this 
Unable to cast object of type 
'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform' 
 to type 
'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RotateTransform'.

when i apply rotation after ranslation from c#.How to remove that error?

Comment: but i want to apply one transformation at a time not all ?

Comment: @user3355043, How would that work??? Either set them individually (overwriting the old one) or use a TransformGroup. If you have a problem setting them individually, you'll need to post some code to get any help.